# HTML input type="date" keeps caching/propogating values

Tags: html, caching, input

**Issue**

Essentially, if I add items to a list, I do an ajax request to add them to an array in the backend and refresh the page.

And each item has two date entries, one for received and one for sent.
If I populate one of the dates, it will change it on the backend via another ajax request, and then fill in the value of that item.

The issue is that due to caching or something, it often happens that when *one* input date value is changed, it "duplicates" over to the other. I think this is a caching issue, as if I inspect the element, the one that was actually altered has a value="xxxx-xx-xx" whereas the cache-broken one has a value="".

**Attempt at Resolution**

I've already tried `$("input").attr("autocomplete", "off"); // Disable input caching`

**Code/Images**

Here's an image of the issue at hand https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJgxK.jpg

When I inspect the element that I wanted to alter,

```
<input type="date" name="2020-08-12" id="sent" class="inp bg-dark border-0 text-center text-white" value="2020-08-12" autocomplete="off">
```

When I inspect the element of the one the cache is breaking,

```
<input type="date" name="" id="rcvd" class="inp bg-dark border-0 text-center text-white" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

Yet both visually display the same date. As you could imagine, this can really confuse users and lead them to try to resolve the issue themselves, potentially breaking more.

Answer (score 1):

You might have used the duplicate selector when selecting the input to alter the value. I suggest each entry should be uniquely identified by an id (ex: UUID) and each input in each entry should have a name.

And then in the HTML, you use the `data-id` attribute to select the entry and the `name` attribute to select the desired input. Finally you can perform altering the input value.

```
$('.entry[data-id="7558c4eb-8c2c-499b-b5cc-ea4ca475b399"] input[name=sentDate]').val("2020-08-08");
```

Sidenote: use `sent` and `rcvd` id for 2 inputs in each entry is not good. Id attribute is meant to be unique to the whole html page.

[Here's my demo code](https://codepen.io/dong-nhan/pen/YzqPvrJ)